# Is there a way to add cypress test steps execution information into allure report?

Tags: cypress, allure

I'm trying to add test step information into an allure report, i use cypress and generate report with allure, report are correctly generate but no details appears in testcases.

I try to use the on('task') without success...

my plugins/index.js contain:

```
...
    on('task', {
        allureTestStep () {
            const testStep = allure.createStep("Initial", () => {
                console.log("First Test")
            });
            testStep()
            return null
        }
    })
...
```

and i call it with:

```
cy.task('allureTestStep')
```

in my test.

No log in console only two error:

```
allure-js-commons: Unexpected startStep() of initial. There is no parent step
First Test
allure-js-commons: Unexpected endStep(). There are no any steps running
```

and in the report nothing is displayed(no error, no step detail).

Any help is welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the cypress-allure plugin and you can set it to show cypress commands in the test results. If you call cy.log those also get placed there. It's pretty nice.

```
    it(`Should have title of ${treeListTitle}`, () => {
      cy.log('title should be set');
      ...
    }
```

Notice in the allure results where that is printed out.

[image]